# Android Media Player stop after 3 activities

Tags: android, view, android-activity, media-player

I am trying to have a song im my app for all the activitie.
I setup MediaPlayer in the first Activity and it play all activities but in the game Activity it stop. I try to create one more Media in the game activity but it not play

**First Activity:**

```
public class MainStage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


 private Button newGameBtn,highScoreBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_game);
    final MediaPlayer themeSong =MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_song);
    themeSong.start();
    newGameBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.new_game);
    newGameBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    highScoreBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.high_score_btn);

    highScoreBtn.setOnClickListener(this);



}
```

**game Activity:**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    club=new Club();
    clubView = new ClubView(this, club);
    mole=new Mole();
    stageView=new StageView(this);
    moleView=new MoleView(this,mole);
    pointsView=new PointsView(this);

    time=new Time(this);
    timerView=new TimerView(this, time);

    allViews=new AllViews(this);
    allViews.setViews(stageView, moleView, pointsView, timerView,clubView);
    setContentView(allViews);
    MediaPlayer themeSong =MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_song);
    themeSong.start();

    allViews.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener)this);
```